# Child element hover, effect Parent

Tags: html, css, hover, css-selectors

I know how can I make "parent hover, child action" with

```
.parent:hover > .child{background:#a4d186;}
```

but I want this if possible:

```
.parent < .child:hover{blabla}
```

Comment: sorry I am new. but thanks

Comment: If child is hovered, so is the parent. Does this not work for you?

Comment: @Salman A it selects child too. I only need it to effect parent.

Comment: As stated above, CSS does not (currently) provide you a mechanism to select parent. If you can edit your question and state what you are trying to achieve may be someone could provide an alternate method. jQuery could be used, if that is an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no selectors like that yet but you can use "~" selector.
Here's an excerpt from `w3.org`

> The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~)
>   character that  separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two  sequences share the same parent in
>   the document tree and the element represented  by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element  represented by the
>   second one.

So you can do it like that:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent-like-div">Do Something</div>
<div class="to-be-controlled">Control me</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent-like-div:hover ~ .to-be-controlled
{your code apply on .to-be-controlled when you hover .parent-like-div}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7grfeod/

Comment: Thank you it's the thing I need. it can only selects after. but thanks.